# Accessing an unaccessible backwards directory in javaScript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My server is pointed at `localhost/_mainDir/`. I need `jsFile.js` to access `phpFile.php`, however this is out of reach for `jsFile.js`.

How can I achieve this? I know that javaScript cannot access directories behind what the server is pointing to; however I do not want to change where my server is pointing due to security reasons.

Here's my directory structure:

```
projectDir -> _mainDir -> index.php
                       -> jsDir -> jsFile.js
           -> phpFile.php
```

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <script src="jsDir/jsFile.js"></script>
   </head>
</html>
```

jsFile.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post("../../phpFile.php", {
        x: 3
    }, function(data) {
        alert(data);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options.

1. You can setup a Symlink to that php file, as long as your webserver is setup to follow symlinks this would work - with that being said you may as well just move the file which will cause the same security issue you talk about.
2. You create another PHP file which the js file can communicate with, which then passes arguments to the ../../phpFile.php and handles the response from phpFile.php back to the $.post - that way your not exposing the phpFile.php and only the particular call made from the client side javascript.

Javscript calls from the front end can be somewhat controlled with CSRF tokens

http://bkcore.com/blog/code/nocsrf-php-class.html

This will allow you to include a CSRF token with the javascript call to the new file that proxies the request to phpFile.php

That way A. you know the request is coming from your frontend (CSRF), B. your only exposing what is required to the frontend.

EDIT: change POST, to arguments using $argv[0]

Comment: How are you supposed to make a PHP file post to another PHP file?

Comment: Maybe POST is the wrong description. PHP arguments. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php